# mongoose using limit in aggregate

Tags: database, mongoose, match, limit

Im trying to set a limit on how many documents get returned with my aggregate method, so far Ive found the $limit function but was unable to incorporate it into my code which looks like this:

```
    User.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "storage._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(d.key) } },
        { "$unwind": "$storage" },
        { "$match": { "storage._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(d.key) } },
        { "$group": {
             "_id": "$_id",
             "storage": { "$push": "$storage" }
        }},
    ])
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where have you tried? what is the problem? just put last stage `{ $limit: 10 }` the 10 is number of documents that you want in result.

Comment: Ive tried putting it directly behind the group stage like this:
`{ "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "storage": { "$push": "$storage" }}},
{ $limit: 10 }`
but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: *doesnt seem to work* => will not help us to understand your problem, please provide error/problem that you are getting, show some example document and expected result.

Comment: after I receive the aggregated documents/objects I get every document that matches the aggregate (which is around 21 - instead of the amount specified in { $limit: 10 }), there is no error message.

Comment: it should work, i am sure you are doing something wrong. still i can't help you with this information.

Comment: just figured it out, still, thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I had to put the limit function after my match function, not after the group one, it looks something like this:

```
{ "$match": { "storage.name": {$regex: regex} } },
{ "$limit" : 5 },
{ "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "storage": { "$push": "$storage" }}}
```